# Laravel, why do I have so many queries?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

**Controller**

```
    $attendees = Attendee::with('User')->get();
    return View::make('admin.attendees.index', compact('attendees'));
```

**Attendee model**

```
public function user()                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |        if( !( $user->hasRole('admin') || $user->hasRole('programmer') ))
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |            return Redirect::to('/');
    return $this->belongsTo('User');                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($attendees as $attendee)
      <td>{{link_to_route('admin.users.show', $attendee->user->username, $attendee->user->id)}}</td>
@endforeach
```

**223 queries**

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '4' limit 1600μs
select `roles`.*, `assigned_roles`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `assigned_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `assigned_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `assigned_roles`.`role_id` where `assigned_roles`.`user_id` = '4'630μs
select * from `attendees`1.24ms
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('5', '1', '3', '8', '9', '10')780μs
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '5' limit 1680μs
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '5' limit 1650μs
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '5' limit 1680μs
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '5' limit 1590μs
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '1' limit 1
 <continues like so for each user id>
```

I am using [phpdebugbar](https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar) to show the queries.

**Migration**

```
Schema::table('attendees', function(Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                                   ->onDelete('cascade')
                                   ->onUpdate('no action');
```

Am I doing something wrong that is causing the query to be run over and over again?

Comment: Can you show your defined relationship in the Attendee model please?

Comment: From the query I can understand you are using `Zizaco/entrust` package.
I think that might be your problem. In your view you return a collection. You don't query a collection. A collection is already loaded and you present it through blade. If you were using a presenter then it would be a different case.

Comment: @Chris updated to show my relation in Attendee. @akad0 Yes, I am using `Zizaco/confide/entrust`. Correct me if I'm wrong, In my controller, Laravel does queries on attendee and users to return a collection to my view that has the attendees and related users. In my view I just want to access the collection but it seems like it is doing more queries.

Comment: I believe your eager load should be `$attendees = Attendee::with('user')->get();` with a lowercase U.

Comment: you are right i just noticed that myself after I posted the update. I will accept your answer if you make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eager load should be the name of the relationship function, not the relationship's model, and it's apparently case sensitive:

```
$attendees = Attendee::with('user')->get();
```